# Data Structure in Rails to sort and lookup on multiple values

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I'm working with this program that, after entering a bunch of information about your golf game, calculates your handicap. Then, on the side (like in Excel), I've got a table that lists a golf course name, a max handicap to play, and distance.

I want a way to implement this table with the golf course name, handicap, and distance info into my program in the following way: Once the program calculates your handicap, it looks at this table, and (through a sort perhaps), finds all the courses where your handicap is lower than the max handicap of the course. Then, from those courses it sorts to find the top three by shortest distance.

I hope that makes sense. What's the best way to get this to work? Should I create a table that stores these values or an array of some sort?

Comment: Yeah I've got the user's handicap stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a table called "courses" that stores golf course names, distances, max handicaps, and whatever else. Then in your controller do something like:

```
@user = current_user //or however you're finding your user
@courses = Course.where("max_handicap >= ?", @user.handicap).order("distance ASC").limit(3)
```

This assumes that there are columns in your courses table named "max_handicap" and "distance", and a column in your users table named "handicap". The query finds all the courses with handicaps >= the users handicap, orders them by distance shortest to longest, and takes the first three. Then to display them in your view, do something like:

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <h1><%= course.name %></h1>
  <h2>Handicap: <%= course.max_handicap %></h2>
  <h3>Course Distance: <%= course.distance %></h3>
<% end %>
```